# Find closest span with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find the text contained within a span with class `menu-item-text`.

If `subListToShow` is my `ul` then I thought this should work but it gives a blank alert.

Thanks
P

```
    <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
        <span class="menu-item-text">AIRS</span>
    </span>
</a>
<ul class="static">
    <li class="static">

alert(subListToShow.closest('span .menu-item-text').text());
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a space between span and .menu-item-text. This means it will select the first *child* of the span with the `.menu-item-text` class.

Just remove the space in the selector to solve your issue:

```
... closest('span.menu-item-text')
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul-Jan but that still shows nothing in the alert ... alert(subListToShow.closest('span.menu-item-text').text());

Comment: And if I try to do this I get 'undefined' alert(subListToShow.closest('span.additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow').html());